# The perl module Params Validate needs a Compiler

Tags: perl, module

I am working to install Circos and have gotten everything installed for perl except for Params::Validate. I downloaded the gzip for the module, ran Build make and ./Build, which resulted in this error message:

```
(base) Tue Jun 15 ashleyschumann ~/Params-Validate-0.95./Build
Building Params-Validate
Error: no compiler detected to compile 'lib/Params/Validate.c'.  Aborting
```

It is listed as missing when I pull all circos modules

```
(base) Tue Jun 15 ashleyschumann ~/Params-Validate-0.95circos -modules
ok       1.42 Carp
ok       0.45 Clone
ok       2.63 Config::General
ok       3.67 Cwd
ok      2.167 Data::Dumper
ok       2.55 Digest::MD5
ok       2.85 File::Basename
ok       3.67 File::Spec::Functions
ok     0.2311 File::Temp
ok       1.51 FindBin
ok       0.39 Font::TTF::Font
ok       2.73 GD
ok        0.2 GD::Polyline
ok       2.49 Getopt::Long
ok       1.16 IO::File
ok      0.430 List::MoreUtils
ok       1.56 List::Util
ok       0.01 Math::Bezier
ok   1.999806 Math::BigFloat
ok       0.07 Math::Round
ok       0.08 Math::VecStat
ok    1.03_01 Memoize
ok       1.76 POSIX
missing            Params::Validate
ok       1.69 Pod::Usage
ok       2.05 Readonly
ok 2017060201 Regexp::Common
ok       2.86 SVG
ok       1.19 Set::IntSpan
ok     1.6611 Statistics::Basic
ok       2.62 Storable
ok       1.20 Sys::Hostname
ok       2.03 Text::Balanced
ok       0.62 Text::Format
ok     1.9764 Time::HiRes
```

I next tried using conda install which threw:

```
base) Tue Jun 15 ashleyschumann ~conda install -c bioconda perl-params-validate
conda install -c bioconda perl-params-validate
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): \ conda install -c bioconda perl-params-valid\ conda install -c bioconda perl-params-validdone
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/ashleyschumann/opt/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - perl-params-validate


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  perl-carp          bioconda/osx-64::perl-carp-1.38-pl526_3
  perl-exporter      bioconda/osx-64::perl-exporter-5.72-pl526_1
  perl-extutils-mak~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-extutils-makemaker-7.36-pl526_1
  perl-module-imple~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-module-implementation-0.09-pl526_2
  perl-module-runti~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-module-runtime-0.016-pl526_1
  perl-params-valid~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-params-validate-1.29-pl526h1de35cc_1
  perl-try-tiny      bioconda/osx-64::perl-try-tiny-0.30-pl526_1
  perl-xsloader      bioconda/osx-64::perl-xsloader-0.24-pl526_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? Invalid choice: conda install -c bioconda perl-params-validate
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Invalid choice: conda install -c bioconda perl-params-validatconda install -c bioconda perl-params-validaty
Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.
```

Has anyone had any luck with a similar issue?

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: It's referring to a C compiler. Specifically, the one used to build `perl` itself, and whose name is given by `perl -V:cc`. (For me, it was `gcc` invoked using the `cc` symlink, so that command outputs `cc`.)  Many Perl modules are actually written in C for performance reasons.

Comment: Have you installed [Command Line Tools](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/install-command-line-tools-on-macos-catalina-anansewaa-com-6f8c63120fd8) ? It includes command line development tools such as gcc

Comment: Thanks all for the response. I just installed the command line tools. It still is showing that there isn't a compiler. Do I need to add the compiler to my path or anything special to be able to use it?

Comment: So I just tried again after updating CPAN and got this error `cpan[4]> install Params::Validate
Running install for module 'Params::Validate'
  DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.30.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/ashleyschumann/.cpan/build/Params-Validate-1.30-12
  DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.30.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.30.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error`

Comment: *"It still is showing that there isn't a compiler"* What is the output from running `which gcc` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error, turns out if you're using perl from the miniconda3 library, then you'll need to install the gcc compiler for miniconda.

```
conda install -c anaconda gcc_linux-64
```

then rerun your install commands, and circos should work!